# php code not outputting utf 8 characters?

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I have Database settings as `UTF8 GENERAL CI` as collation for my table. But when I try to output using the following PHP code, Question marks show up in place of UTF characters (I am trying to print Regional language characters)...

Following is my code:

```
<?php
class Article implements JsonSerializable{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $content;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getContent() {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public static function getById($id) {
        $db = newMysqli ();
        $query = "select * from articles where _id=?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $query ) or dieOnError ( $db );
        $stmt->bind_param ( "i", $id ) or dieOnError ( $db );
        $stmt->execute () or dieOnError ( $db );

        $member = new Article();
        $stmt->bind_result ( $member->id, $member->title, $member->content);
        $stmt->fetch () or dieOnError ( $db );
        $stmt->close ();
        return $member;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(){
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}
```

Comment: PHP certainly outputs any string unmodified here, that is not the issue. Question is what character encoding you send to you client and if your client uses a font that actually has glyphs for those characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: The table/column is probably `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Have you tried `SET NAMES UTF8` query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the file encoding to UTF-8. (Encoding menu in Notepad++ -> convert to UTF-8)